Warping in a raycaster renderer made in unity
I am quite inexperienced with unity but i made a raycaster today but it had weird warping and i don't know how to fix it, and would highly appreciate if anyone wants to help! :D
picture of the issue
The code for the renderer:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class renderer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject square;
    public int rays = 50;
    public int fov = 70;
    public float ray_dist = 20;
    public float fall_off_dist = 5;
    private float cam_width;
    private float cam_height;
    private float cam_edge;
    private float ray_angle;
    
    private void create_slices()
    {
        for (int current_slice = 0; current_slice < rays; current_slice++)
        {
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(square, cam.transform);
            clone.name = "slice" + current_slice.ToString();
            clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(cam_width / rays, cam_height);
            clone.transform.position = new Vector3(cam_edge + (clone.transform.localScale.x / 2) + (cam_width / rays * current_slice), 0);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 cam_dim = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, cam.nearClipPlane)) - cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, cam.nearClipPlane));
        cam_width = cam_dim.x;
        cam_height = -cam_dim.y;
        cam_edge = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, cam.nearClipPlane)).x;
        create_slices();
    }

    private void change_slice(RaycastHit2D raycast, float current_ray)
    {
        if (raycast)
        {
            float dist_mult = math.clamp((fall_off_dist - raycast.distance) / fall_off_dist, 0, 1);
            Color hit_color = raycast.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
            GameObject slice = GameObject.Find("slice" + current_ray.ToString());
            slice.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = hit_color * dist_mult;
            slice.transform.localScale = new Vector3(slice.transform.localScale.x, cam_height * dist_mult);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {   
        ray_angle = math.radians(fov / (float)rays);
        for (float current_ray = 0f; current_ray < rays; current_ray += 1f)
        {
            float angle1 = math.sin((-ray_angle * (((float)rays - 1) / 2)) + (ray_angle * current_ray));
            float angle2 = math.cos((-ray_angle * (((float)rays - 1) / 2)) + (ray_angle * current_ray));
            Vector3 direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(player.transform.eulerAngles.z, Vector3.forward) * new Vector3(angle1, angle2);
            RaycastHit2D raycast = Physics2D.Raycast(player.transform.position, direction, ray_dist);
            change_slice(raycast, current_ray);
        }
    }
}

i have tried to multiply raycast distance by cos(ray_angle) but it made no difference
